# error: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index using numpy.reshape on a tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, reshape

I am writing a program that analyzes the Cifar-100 dataset using TensorFlow and the Keras included dataset. I am following this tutorial

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification

But I adapted it to the cifar-100 and not the Fashion MNIST. The Fashion MNIST is a dataset with a size of (60000, 28, 28) while the Cifar-100 has a size of (50000, 32, 32, 3).

As I needed my `train_images` to be in 3 dimensions, I tried to write

`train_images.transpose(50000, 32, 32, 3)
train_images.reshape(train_images, (50000, 32, 32))`

but there is the `AxisError: axis 50000 is out of bounds for array of dimension 4`

so I tried only using the reshape function: `train_images.reshape(train_images, (50000, 32, 32))` but I get this `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: `transpose` is used to reorder the axis of an array.  Thus the numbers have to ones like (0,2,1,3).  Read the docs.  The correct use of `reshape` is `x.reshape(n,m,p)`.  Don't repeat the array name.  Again read the docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) But now I have another error : 
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 150000 input samples and 50000 target samples.                                     How do I deal with it?